# Appended loader is shown in DOM but not rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-append

I have been adding loaders in my sites usually before a call to the database and therefor usually before using a `$.post` function.

I have never had any problem until now that I face myself trying to add a loader before some random code which takes a while to be executed.

I can see how the append element is loaded into the DOM but it is not being rendered.

This is the example code which illustrates the problem:

```
$('.demo').click(function(){

    alert("Starting...");

    //won't be rendered until the FOR finishes
    $(this).append(' Loading...');

    for(var i = 0; i<800000000; i++){
     var nothing = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    }

});
```

Here's the living example:
http://jsfiddle.net/88398/1/

How could I make the loader to be rendered before the execution of the following code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because after updating the dom, the browser is not getting any time to repaint the UI till the function completes.

One possible solution to use `setTimeout()` to delay the task which will provide the time for browser to update the UI and then execute the `setTimeout` callback.

```
$('.demo').click(function(){
    alert("Starting...");
    $(this).append(' Loading...');

    setTimeout(function(){
        for(var i = 0; i<800000000; i++){
            var nothing = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        }
    }, 10)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wG5n6/)

The reason is a browser tab runs like a single thread that is at one time the browser can do only a single task. Meaning it can either update the UI or run the script.

In your case you have a function, any changes done with in it(dom update) will take effect only after the completion of the function execution

I hope I got the terminologies correct

Comment: Why don't I have this problem when instead of a loop I have a `$.load` function?

Comment: @Steve Because $.load is asychronous

Comment: The `load` will sent a request to server then the thread execution is completed freeing the browser to do what ever it want till the response comes back

Comment: The solution works but I have tried applying it and it slow down the executing of the code inside the setTimeout for almost x4 times. From around 1 second to 4 seconds having the setTimeout set to `10` miliseconds... Do you know which could be the cause?

Comment: seems fine to me from these two tests http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wG5n6/5/ and http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wG5n6/6/